# Referencing the App server

Tags: node.js, express

New to node and building an expressJS app.

I need to reference the http server and port in an ExpressJS route, how do I do that?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you build it like so

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').Server(app);
```

You can retrieve the server IP and port using

```
server.address() //contains { address: '0.0.0.0', family: 'IPv4', port: 3000 }
```